# How can I prevent Stack Overflow applications from linking my CV?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I don't like the format of the CV on Stack Overflow and would prefer to just attach my resumé, but I don't see how I can prevent Stack Overflow from linking my CV. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Story has now replaced the CV - you might like the format of that better, as the design has gotten a revamp. If you'd still prefer that your application doesn't include a link to your Developer Story, you can always apply anonymously.